# Training a multilayer perceptron in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, weka, perceptron

I am using Weka to implement classification algorithms. I was dealing with *Multilayer Perceptron.* I have some doubts while training the model. I used toy datasets that are already available in Weka. The name of the datasets are `contact-lenses.arff` and `weather.nominal.arff`.

I am attaching some screenshots.

[image]

[image]]

[image]

I was using 5fold cross validation method.

As per the definition available in weka for hidden layer, `There are also wildcard values: 'a' = (attribs + classes) / 2, 'i' = attribs, 'o' = classes , 't' = attribs + classes.`

For the 1st screenshot `a` should be (No. of attribute + classes)/2 = (4+3)/2 = 7/2 = 3.5 = 4

So we can see the 4 nodes in the hidden layer.

Now for screenshot 3, (4+2)/2 = 3. But we can see 5 nodes in the hidden layer. Why there is a mismatch between actual nodes and calculated nodes?

Secondly if we consider 1st two screenshots we can see age uses three different values in the model namely, young, pre-prebyopic, prebyopic. However, attribute spectacle-prescrip has two different values namely, myope and hypermetrope but only one value hypermetrope used to train the model. What about the other values `myope`? Same doubts raised for other attributes as well.

A brief explanation will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

By default, [MultilayerPerceptron](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/MultilayerPerceptron.html) applies the [unsupervised NominalToBinary](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NominalToBinary.html) filter to the input data, which will increase the number of attributes for non-binary nominal attributes. That explains the different number of nodes in the hidden layer.

Also, a binary nominal attribute can be modeled with just a single node (below threshold is one label, above threshold the other one) - and NominalToBinary, with its default settings, does not change these types of attributes.

Comment: I did not get your point.  I found the NominalToBinary transfer method from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48100/changing-attributes-from-nominal-to-binary. If this is the method how could it increase the number of attributes? For the 2nd part of the answer can you please explain it more precisely?

Comment: I linked the Javadoc of the NominalToBinary filter in my answer, allowing you to read up on it. Simply select that filter in the preprocess panel and see what happens to the input data. A neural node (eg a sigmoid) has two states, just like a binary attribute - I'm not sure what's not to understand...

Comment: I can not understand the 2nd part of my question. Why some answers of an attribute is selected and why other answers of an attribute is discarded?

Comment: A binary attribute `att1` has two values, e..g, `A` and `B`. Assuming that a node is built for `att1=A` then the label `A` is chosen when the node is activated and `B` when not. Nothing gets discarded, two labels = two states (on/off).

Comment: I trained the model several times but I always got this set of attribute values. So the portion that you defined as not activated(like B), I never got deactivated bunch of values as activated bunch of values.

Comment: Unless you change the random seed or parameters of the algorithm, you will always get the same results back (*repeatable experiments*). If you swap the order of the binary labels in your ARFF file, the MultilayerPerceptron will pick the other label in the model. From what I can tell, what label it picks has nothing to do with the data itself, but with the order of the labels.

Comment: I have changed the seed for contact-lense dataset. By default,  multilayer perceptron has predefine seed is 0. I changed it to 2. However, there is no change in the result. again the same result. What do you mean by parameters change? The whole datset has predefined.

Comment: Parameters like number of hidden layers, eith varying number of nodes, different preprocessing, etc. Seed value to changed as part of Explorer settings, not MLP, under the *More options* button.